# R - Merge many Columns and leave several

Tags: r, merge, na

I want to merge a structure like this removing the NAs:
We have 8 "Blocks" of Data with 10 Variables each. For each participant only one of these 8 Blocks is answered completely, i.e. 10 valid variables / participant. --> 80 Columns

VP Var1 Var 10 Var 11 Var 20 Var 21 Var30 .........

1   2     3    NA    NA    NA   NA

2   NA  NA     3     5     NA   NA

3   NA  NA     NA   NA     5     4

The final version should look like --> 10 Columns

VP Var1 Var 2 Var 3 Var4 ... Var10

1   2    3  .........

2   3    5  .........

3   5    4  ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to insert a function to be applied to each row in a call to the `apply` function. You can wrap the `apply` call in a `data.frame` call, if you want that.

```
new.dat <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) return(x[!is.na(x)]))
```

Comment: That's really very simple and elegant - Thanks